# How to Set Up a Cronjob to Reindex Magento 2 inside Docker

Tags: cron, magento2, reindex

I'd like to know how to set up a cron job to reindex Magento 2. I have installed crontab in my docker by running

```
apt-get install cron
```

inside my php container, then I run

```
crontab -e
```

and I'm able to see and edit my cronjob file. So I set up a command to execute every minute like this:

```
* * * * * php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I close the editor and says that a new crontab was installed. I run `crontab -l`, and indeed my command is there, but nothing happens. What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake is the path, you need to type the full path for your commands.

For instance, php is usually located at `/usr/local/bin/php` but you make sure of this by running `which php` inside your php container. For the `bin/magento` path you can just enter bin folder and type `pwd` and get the full path.

The second mistake is that you might beeing forgetting to start the cronjob by running `service cron start`. Also you can check status at any time with `/etc/init.d/cron status`